# Clojure null pointer exception

Tags: java, exception, clojure, functional-programming

I have the following code

```
(def lampo1 [-20 -18 -30 -5 7 15 25 18 7 0 -15 -10])
(def lampo2 [-21 -11 -31 -5 8 16 35 18 1 2 -15 -20])

(defn -main
  [& args]

  (let [keskiarvot (map #(/ (reduce + %) (count %)) (map vector lampo1 lampo2))] (
    (println keskiarvot)

    (let [positiiviset (filter pos? keskiarvot)](
      (println positiiviset)

      (let [posKeskiarvo (double (/ (reduce + positiiviset) (count positiiviset)))](
        (println posKeskiarvo))))))))
```

Which outputs the following

```
(-41/2 -29/2 -61/2 -5 15/2 31/2 30 18 4 1 -15 -15)
(15/2 31/2 30 18 4 1)
12.66666666666667
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException, compiling:(/tmp/form-init1433117969168569713.clj:1:73)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7391)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7317)
        at clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:275)
        at clojure.main$init_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:277)
        at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:277)
        at clojure.main$initialize.invokeStatic(main.clj:308)
        at clojure.main$null_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:342)
        at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:339)
        at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:421)
        at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:384)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at v501.core$_main.invokeStatic(core.clj:16)
        at v501.core$_main.doInvoke(core.clj:7)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:375)
        at user$eval5.invokeStatic(form-init1433117969168569713.clj:1)
        at user$eval5.invoke(form-init1433117969168569713.clj:1)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6927)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6917)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7379)
        ... 14 more
```

So the code seems to run till end, but null pointer exception is thrown. What causes it? Also, what is wrong with the Clojure's stack trace? Seems like creator of the language was lazy and didn't implement exception abstraction at clojure level at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you wrapped the body of let in extra parens, so effectively `nil`, the result of `println` is invoked as a function. Remove the parens and it works like expected:

```
(defn -main
  [& args]
  (let [keskiarvot (map #(/ (reduce + %) (count %)) (map vector lampo1 lampo2))] 
    (println keskiarvot)
    (let [positiiviset (filter pos? keskiarvot)]
      (println positiiviset)
      (let [posKeskiarvo (double (/ (reduce + positiiviset) (count positiiviset)))]
        (println posKeskiarvo)))))
```

Comment: Is it other wise good or bad practice to nest lets like this, if I need/want to store the intermediate results or make the code more clear? As far as I know def would make the var global, which is not intended. I think this is easier to understand than just chaining everything together, as those let binding names kinda documents what is happening.

Comment: Inline defs are fine for debugging purposes, but not for the final code. But you can also just write:
```
(let [x ...
       _ (println x)
       y ...
       _ (println y)]
  (+ x y)
``` to avoid nesting the lets.